# MongoDB transforming data using aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following data in a collection.

```
[
    {name: "a", status: 1},
    {name: "a", status: 2},
    {name: "a", status: 3},
    {name: "b", status: 1},
    {name: "b", status: 4},
    {name: "c", status: 1},
    {name: "c", status: 1},
    {name: "c", status: 5}
]
```

I want it to be transformed as:

```
{
    names: ["a", "b", "c"],
    statuses: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    count: [
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [2, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    ]
}
```

Explanation:

1. names will have the unique list of name attribute
2. statuses will have the unique list of status attribute
3. Count contains array of count of status per name

   1. For example the first count array is [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
   2. Which means:

      1. There is only one status:1 for the name a
      2. There is only one status:2 for the name a and so on..
   3. If you take the 3rd array [2, 0, 0, 0, 1]

      1. The name c has status:1 two times
      2. There is no 2 or 3 or 4 but it has one 5

**Can you suggest the corresponding aggregation function or equivalent?**

Edit:
I just have this so far:

```
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {environment: "$name", status: "$status"}, 
      count:{$sum: 1}
    }
  }
])
```

Thank you

Comment: Good! Now can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have this so far..

db.collection1.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {name: "$name", status: "$status"}, 
      count:{$sum: 1}
    }
  }
])

Comment: Don't post your code here. use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33443491/edit) on your question.

Comment: i added it to the question